# Google Drive in ios : Authenticating to Drive programmatically without opening Google Login page

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

Is there any possible way to login to google drive by providing hardcoded user email and password  without opening its `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` View Controller in our app.

Comment: *hardcoded user email and password* ? No, please don't.

Comment: My requirement is not to show authentication page inside my app

Comment: No, that's not possible. Breaks all sorts of concepts of OAuth, since OAuth is per-user, per-application.